# Android. Data binding not working after recreating the fragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using MVVM with databinding. After I navigate (with jetpack navigation) from fragment A to fragment B, and then back to fragment A the view of fragment A is recreated.

To solve this problem I create a field in my fragment class to save my view:

```
private var contentView: View? = null

  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {       
        if (contentView == null) {
            contentView= FragmentPhotoDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
                lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
                viewBinding = this
                vm = viewModel
            }.root
        }
        return contentView !!
    }
```

And it works, but now after recreating the view of fragment, the data biding does not work for me.

The view model updates the data on live data, but subscribers do not react to it in any way.

Please help me solve this problem.

**P.S.** If I do not save the view in the field, but every time after call the onCreateView() I create a new one, then the data binding works.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
  private var _binding: View? = null
  /*
   *Transform to immutable - use this for updating binding
   *properties like in data binding
   */
   private val binding: View get() = _binding!!

  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {       
        _binding = FragmentPhotoDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.apply {
                lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
                viewBinding = this
                vm = viewModel
            }
        }
        return binding.root!!
    }

  override fun onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy()
    //Nullify since it is not automatically garbage collected
     _binding = null
}
```

if you want to reuse previously inflated, you can add null check on `_binding` in `onCreateView` and remove nullifying of `_binding` in `onDestroy`

```
if (_binding == null) { 
   _binding = FragmentPhotoDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but I need to prevent fragment view recreation, and for this I store fragment view inside field, and after onDestroyView() and recall onCreateView() I return previously created view.

Comment: Please see updated answer.